# Is it possible to have more than one token field in a rendering variant?

Tags: sxa

In SXA 1.8 I had a rendering variant with a VariantSection, with a `style` key on the Data attributes field, with value of `background-image:url($(PromoImage));background-position: $(Horizontal Focal Point) $(Vertical Focal Point);`

This was working totally fine, but when upgrading to SXA 10.1.0 I now get this error:

```
[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) +60
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +14338200
Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderRenderingVariantFieldProcessor.GetAttributeTokenValues(Item item, T attributes, Action`3 collectionAction, MatchCollection matches, String value, String key) +326
Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderRenderingVariantFieldProcessor.GetAttributeTokenValues(Item item, IDictionary`2 attributes, MatchCollection matches, String value, String key) +219
Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderRenderingVariantFieldProcessor.GetVariantAttributes(RenderingVariantFieldBase variantField, Item item, Object model) +319
Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderRenderingVariantFieldProcessor.AddWrapperDataAttributes(RenderingVariantFieldBase variantField, RenderVariantFieldArgs args, HtmlGenericControl tag) +49
Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSection.RenderField(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +699
Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderVariantFieldProcessor.Process(RenderVariantFieldArgs args) +138
```

If I change the field to only have one token in it, it works fine. It doesn't matter which token I keep. Why do multiple tokens now break it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this myself by overriding the following:

- Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderSection
- Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Pipelines.RenderVariantField.RenderTitle

With this code:

```
protected override void GetAttributeTokenValues(
        Item item,
        IDictionary<string, string> attributes,
        MatchCollection matches,
        string value,
        string key)
{
    //this.GetAttributeTokenValues(item, attributes, (collection, k, v) => collection.Add(k, v), matches, value, key);

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        string attributeTokenValue = this.GetAttributeTokenValue(match.Groups[1].Value, item);
        value = value.Replace(match.Value, attributeTokenValue);
        if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            attributes[key] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            attributes.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I have raised this to sitecore support and they confirmed the issue with public ref 460090. As I have fixed this myself I didn't request a hotfix.